# Scrolling view similar to that of a camera app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I'm curious if there's anything that comes standard with Android that looks exactly like this.

If not, do we have a customised approach to accomplishing it?

[image]

Comment: How did you achieve this?

Comment: Check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73953044/8936827

Comment: Thanks. You must accept the answer which helped you

Answer (score 1):

There is no standart view that looks like this one.
But you can write it by yourself with help of `RecyclerView`, `SnapHelper` and `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`
See more:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SnapHelper
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration

Also, take a look at this example, which implements this:
https://gist.github.com/Ilyshka991/a2759dd564da41859ad5ebac96f368e5

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do - the tricky part is the extra space at the start of the list. We can do that by adding a dummy item to the list with a fixed width.

First get a basic item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100sp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="1/800"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

The important thing here is the `minWidth` (in sp) which gives each item a consistent size. You could make it a fixed size too, if you want - this way just allows for longer labels. Really that value should be a *dimension resource*, e.g. `@dimen/stops_item_width` but we'll get to that later

---

Now you need an adapter:

```
class StopsAdapter(private val items: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<StopsViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val PADDING = 0
        const val ITEM = 1
    }

    // treat the first item in the list as the header
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = if (position == 0) PADDING else ITEM

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StopsViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = StopsItemBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return if (viewType == PADDING) StopsViewHolder.Padding(binding)
        else StopsViewHolder.Item(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StopsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // need to offset the lookup, since item 0 in the list is displayed at position 1
        if (holder is StopsViewHolder.Item) holder.binding.label.text = items[position - 1]
    }

    // add 1 to the list size to account for the padding object
    override fun getItemCount() = items.size + 1
}

sealed class StopsViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // basically reusing the same layout, just forcing a fixed width on it
    class Padding(binding: StopsItemBinding) : StopsViewHolder(binding.root) {
        init {
            with(binding.label) {
                // padding needs to be half the screen width, minus half an item (so it's centred)
                val metrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
                // really this 100 should be a dimension resource that the XML uses too, defined in one place
                val minItemWidth = 100 * metrics.scaledDensity
                width = ((metrics.widthPixels - minItemWidth) / 2f).roundToInt()
            }
        }
    }

    class Item(val binding: StopsItemBinding) : StopsViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

The comments explain it, but there are basically two types of `ViewHolder` - one that displays items, and one that has a fixed width and only appears as the first item in the list. That size is calculated when the VH is created, and it depends on that *item width* in the XML (so it can offset enough that the first real item is centred). This is why it would be best as a resource - so it's only defined in one place, instead of hardcoded here *and* in the XML, where you'd need to change both if you ever tweak it.

---

And then you just need to set it up on your `RecyclerView`

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view)
        with(binding.recyclerView) {
            adapter = StopsAdapter(listOf(
                "Auto", "1/4000", "1/3200", "1/1600", "1/1250", "1/1000", "1/800"
            ))
            layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            // snaps the items to the middle of the screen
            LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(this)
        }
    }
}
```

And that's about it!

[image: The working layout]

Comment: Thank you, mate. I'll look into it and get back to you.